# Adding Android platform to Facebook Developer Console after building from Expo/React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, expo

I have been building an app in React-Native using Expo and I am getting ready to upload beta versions for iOS and Android. I am using 'Facebook Sign in' and while developing and using the Expo Go app, I had no issues making it work. However, on Android, after making a native build, Facebook is no longer working. The authentication modal pops up, asks for the user's login info, but then it just hangs on a blank screen. No error and the modal does not dismiss. I am using the Facebook provider in the 'expo-auth-session' package for this but I think the problem lies in the Facebook Dev Console. When I try to add an android platform to my facebook account, I provide the key hash with no issue, but when I try to add my package name (as it is defined in my app.json file) I get an error saying "There was a problem verifying this package name". And if I try to press the "Confirm Ownership" button, I get another error saying "Error found while validating app-ads.txt". The problem is, I don't have my app listed on the google play store yet because I want to test it as a native build rather than inside the Expo Go app. I'm not sure if this is what is causing the Facebook sign in to not work in my native app, but I have followed all the other documentation provided by expo and this is the only issue I have run into. Is there a way to verify my app package name before submitting to the Play Store. And do I actually need to have an "app-ads.txt" file somewhere in my project? I currently do not have ads or any form of monetization in my app.